# How to implement 2 distinct timeouts with Pyramid Authentication policy?

Tags: pyramid, restful-authentication

I'm writing a pyramid application with both web pages, and an API called from a mobile device.

For the web pages, I set the a timeout of 2 hours :

```
authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(
    settings['secret'],
    callback=groupfinder,
    hashalg='sha512',
    timeout=3600*2,
    reissue_time=360*2
    )
```

However, I would like that when the user logs in via the mobile app, the timeout is much longer (i.e. several days). Is there a simple way to do this ?

I didn't see anything with timeout, but I saw the remember() function can take a max_age parameter. So maybe I could remove the timeout (or set it longer), and use the max_age parameter: 2h for web, and 2 days for the mobile app. Is it a good idea ? Would there be a notable difference, or any vulnerability ?